# How to get the elapsed time in milliseconds in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, time

I tried using `t1=$(date +%s%N)` to get the time in nanoseconds, but I kept in getting this error:

```
./script.sh: line 10: 1292460931N: value too great for base (error token is "1292460931N")
```

I looked up online and it seems that you can use the "time" command, however I can't find a good example of using the time command. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you trying to get the time your script took to run or the time something in your script took to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, a couple of things here.

First, not a lot of systems can give you a time that actually accurate to nanoseconds anyway.

Now, using time, either as `/usr/bin/time` or the shell builtin (bash: `help time`) is very easy.  If the command you want to time is `foo1`, then

```
$ time foo
```

will return the elapsed time as three lines on stderr

```
real 0m0.001s
user 0m0.000s
sys  0m0.000s
```

which you can use any way you like.

If you want to get a better, more accurate timing, execute the command many times.  This can be as simple as writing a short loop

```
time for i in 0 1 2 3 4; do foo; done
```

will do `foo` five times and give you the total time.  You probably want to do more than 5 iterations, so you'd probably want a counter and a while loop or the like.

Comment: @Tony: You can control the output of Bash's builtin `time` using the `TIMEFORMAT` variable or `/usr/bin/time` using the `-f` option. See `man bash` or `man time`.

Answer (score 6):

The `date` command you're using doesn't support `%N` so your output is literally `1292460931N`.  I tried it on Linux and it worked, but on FreeBSD I see the results you got.  Run that date command in a shell and see what comes out.  Is it possible you're using `busybox`?  Its cut-down date command also omits `%N` but the version I just tried gave me `1292463535%N`.

Comment: do you know any other ways of getting milliseconds granularity?

Comment: @Tony Yes, you can compile a C-program that calls `getitimer()` and `setitimer()` and use your script to call that.